# Gunicorn does not run in docker container when using ENTRYPOINT or CMD

Tags: docker, flask, gunicorn

I have the following Dockerfile and entrypoint.sh script. I do as below, but when I run the container it looks like gunicorn never starts because nothing gets written to log files. The container remains running because I type "docker ps" and I can see it.

I then start a bash process by doing "docker exec -it  /bin/bash" and I can run the gunicorn process from there and then it works.

So basically, it works if I run the container and then log into a bash session and paste the gunicorn command, but it doesn't work otherwise.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
MAINTAINER peter griffin "some@email.com"
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev

WORKDIR /deploy

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn

COPY ./app ./app

COPY [\
    "run.py", \
    "app.db", \
    "entrypoint.sh", \
    "config.py", \
    "gunicorn.conf.py", \
    "./"]

#RUN mkdir ./logs
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /deploy/logs
touch /deploy/logs/error.log
touch /deploy/logs/access.log
tail -n 0 -f /deploy/logs/*.log

exec gunicorn run:app \
    --name greg_docker \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 \
    --workers 2 \
    --log-level=info \
    --log-file=/deploy/logs/error.log \
    --access-logfile=/deploy/logs/access.log \
```

To build:

```
docker build -t greg:latest .
```

To run:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 greg:latest
```

If I'm inside the container in a /bin/bash session, I can paste:

```
exec gunicorn run:app \
    --name greg_docker \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 \
    --workers 2 \
    --log-level=info \
    --log-file=/deploy/logs/error.log \
    --access-logfile=/deploy/logs/access.log
```

And then it does work when I go to http://0.0.0.0:8080 on the docker host.

What is the difference? Why does gunicorn not work on entrypoint.sh?

**update**
I've made a new file, entrypoint2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /deploy/logs
touch /deploy/logs/error.log
exec gunicorn run:app \
    --name greg_docker \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 \
    --log-level=debug \
    --log-file=/deploy/logs/error.log \
    --workers 2
"$@"
```

And I've updated my Dockerfile with the line:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","-x","entrypoint2.sh"]
```

When I run the container I get this:

```
+ mkdir -p /deploy/logs
+ touch /deploy/logs/error.log
+ exec gunicorn run:app --name greg_docker --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --log-level=debug --log-file=/deploy/logs/error.log --workers 2
```

But then the container doesn't do anything, it doesn't stay running.

Comment: Try `docker exec` into the container, and run `sh -x entrypoint.sh`.  This will re-run the entrypoint script and print out each command before it executes.  I'd guess one of the commands there before you get to the `exec gunicorn` isn't returning.

Comment: Ok, I've made the changes above, and still doesn't work. I also tried it with that tail command "tail -n 0 -f /deploy/logs/*.log", which allows the container to keep running, then I did docker exec /bin/bash, and ran entrypoint2.sh from there, and that does work.  Do you think it's something to do with permissions or groups?

Comment: What's in your `gunicorn.conf.py`?

Comment: The following:  daemon = True
accesslog = "logs/access.log"
errorlog = "logs/error.log"

Comment: But I'm not using the gunicorn.conf.py file anymore in entrypoint2.sh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out when running gunicorn, you absolutely need to specify a configuration file.

entrypoint2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /deploy/logs
touch /deploy/logs/error.log
touch /deploy/logs/access.log
cd /deploy
exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 -c docker-gunicorn.conf.py run:app
```

docker-gunicorn.conf.py:

```
accesslog = "/deploy/logs/access.log"
errorlog = "/deploy/logs/error.log"
```

Answer (score 3):

When you `docker run` a container, it starts the ENTRYPOINT (if any), passing the CMD to it as command-line arguments.  When that program or script finishes, the container exits.

In your first iteration, your ENTRYPOINT said:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read all of the log files, blocking forever, printing out new
# content as it appears
tail -n 0 -f /deploy/logs/*.log

# Only then, once that "blocking forever" has finished...
exec gunicorn run:app
```

So the `tail` command was preventing the `gunicorn` from actually starting.  You should have been able to see this by using the shell `-x` option (as in your edit, or by adding a `set -x` line to the script): it will get up to the `tail`, and then just stop.

In a comment you say you set the `daemon = True` [gunicorn option](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#daemon) in a config file.  If gunicorn finds this, then it will fork itself into the background and exit.  From Docker's point of view, it sees the process that it launched as the container entrypoint exit, so the container is done, and it shuts down.  I'm not totally sure what is or isn't causing that config file to get read, but that would cause an early exit.

You need to make sure you're running the server *as a foreground process*.  If you `docker exec` to get a shell in a running container, start the server, and get a command prompt back, then you're invoking it in a way that won't keep the container alive.

Comment: I think the "exec" command might be the culprit because I read it replaces the current process, and elsewhere I read if PID 1 doesn't exist, the docker container stops running.